# Image of segment and stereographic projection

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $\pi:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb S^2-{(0,0,1)}$ be the stereographic projection and let $PQ$ be the segment connecting the points $P,Q$ in the plane.

Is $\pi(PQ)$, image of the segment under the projection, a geodesic on $\mathbb S^2-{(0,0,1)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. There is a circle in the plane corresponding to the equator of the sphere. Take a tangent line to that circle. It cannot be a geodesic. Indeed, any other geodesic (great circle) would intersect the equator, but the image of this line would always stay above the equator (in fact, it will be a "small" circle on the sphere).